# Как вызвать метод, после смены чекед в input?

Tags: javascript

как вызвать метод self.showMore() после того как чекед сменит состояние, а не до

```
<div class="filter-item filter-item-multiple" data-parameter-id="1">
  <div class="filter-item_header">
    <P class="filter-item_item-title">Наполнение</P>
    <span class="filter-item_item-description">Выберите значения:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-item_section">
    <div class="filter-item_section-values">
      <div class="filter-item_section-value">
        <div class="checkbox-input">
          <input id="1_2" type="checkbox" name="style" value="2">
          <label for="1_2" class="filter-item-multiple-value">
               Независимый пружинный блок
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="filter-item_section-value">
        <div class="checkbox-input">
          <input id="1_1" type="checkbox" name="style" value="1">
          <label for="1_1" class="filter-item-multiple-value">
              ППУ ST стандартный                                                 </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

multipleFilter($domElem) {
    var self = this;
    $domElem.on('click', '.filter-item-multiple-value', function (event) {
      var target = event.currentTarget;
      var $parent = $(target).closest('.filter-item-multiple');

      var top = $parent.position().top + $parent.outerHeight(true) / 2;
      self.showMore(top);
    });
  };
```

Comment: мб надо `$(input).change(..)` вешать а не `$(label).click(..)` ?

Comment: да, вот только сейчас додумался)